# @ManyToMany does not return Micronaut's nested data

Tags: jpa, micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm new to Micronaut, and have followed the documentation to set up a REST application, but I can't make a simple list from many to many. When starting the application everything looks normal, the database tables are being generated normally, and the terminal is returning the pageable entities, but it does not return the lists that are nested by the relationship for many.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "unidade")
public class Unidade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    @NotNull
    private String cnpj;

    private String storage;

    private String telefone;

    @Email
    private String email;

    private boolean ativo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "empresa_id")
    private Empresa empresa;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "unidade_produto",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "unidade_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "produto_id"))
    private List<Produto> produtos;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "produto")
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String nome;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "produtos")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Unidade> unidades;
}
```

POST Request:

```json
{
    "nome": "Testando",
    "cnpj": "000.000.000/0000-01",
    "storage": "new",
    "telefone": "0000-0000",
    "email": "teste@gmail.com",
    "ativo": true,
    "empresa": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "produtos": [
        {
        "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "horario": {
        "id": 1
    }
            
}
```

There is no return from nesting entities. Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Are you just wanting the generated JSON to include the expanded object representation of `Product` instances instead of ` [ { "id": 1 } ]`?

Comment: No. I want the product list to be saved in the Unit entity.

Comment: " I want the product list to be saved in the Unit entity." - You haven't shown any code that indicates what you are doing to populate and attempt to save the product list.  Can you show that?

Comment: @Post("/new")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Unidade save(@Body @Valid Unidade unidade) {
        return unidadeService.save(unidade);
    }

Comment: Does the `unidadeService` reference point to a Micronaut Data Repository?

Comment: Yes, reference.

Comment: I managed to solve it, exchanging some notes from my Repository.